# Angular Translate Href _blank doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've implemented angular translate and it's working well so far.
I do have one problem with the following code though:

```
REGISTER_RULES_ACCEPT : ' I have read the <a href="rules" target=_blank">Rules</a> and hereby accept them.<span class="registration-important">*</span>',
```

Html Implementation:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="rules"><a translate="REGISTER_RULES_ACCEPT"></a></input>
```

It displays correctly and everything, when going over the link with my mouse it shows the link in the bar. However when I click it, nothing happens. I can right mouse or mid mouse click it and open it in another tab, but left clicking it does nothing. Any idea whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have anchor `a` tag in translation then just bind it in `span` or paragraph element in view code. So, your template code can be:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="rules" />
<span translate="REGISTER_RULES_ACCEPT"></span>
```

[**Plunker Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/V8uQ9aGxlqiS4oQbdRw1?p=preview)

Comment: Works. Thank you :)

Comment: @KonstantinSchlegel Welcome! You can accept the answer if it works :)